# Read from the provided column index/name to last column : apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi-4

Here is the sample data. First row is header.

```
Demo1           Demo2           Demo3           Demo4           Demo5
DummyText1      DummyText2      DummyText3      DummyText4      DummyText5
DummyText11     DummyText21     DummyText31     DummyText41     DummyText51
```

I want to read data after the provided column index/name till last column. However with the below code specified column index get skipped.

```
for (Row row : xssfSheet4) {
    if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    //
    for (Cell cell1 : row) {
        if (cell1.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
          continue;
        }
        //
    }
}
```

With the above code, Demo2 column skipped and read as

```
Demo1           Demo3           Demo4           Demo5
DummyText1      DummyText3      DummyText4      DummyText5
DummyText11     DummyText31     DummyText41     DummyText51
```

However, it should read as

```
Demo3           Demo4           Demo5
DummyText3      DummyText4      DummyText5
DummyText31     DummyText41     DummyText51
```

Comment: `<= 1` instead of `== 1`?

Comment: So silly mistake. Thank you @luk2302